# Do I need to stage the 'vcpkg' directory to git

Tags: c++, git, vcpkg

I am new to c++ development environment from javascript dev environment. Comparing to javascript package management, c++ is complicated. I found `vcpkg` that like `npm` for cpp.

#### The question :- When it comes to 'vcpkg' do I need to stage all files (to git) that contains in `/vcpkg` directory. Or just add it to `.gitignore`.

The project diretory :-

[image: project-directory]

The `/vcpkg` directory contains a lot of files, that why I asked.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't upload the dependencies to your repository. The correct thing to do is to use vcpkg in manifest mode. This way vcpkg.json package will be used to keep track of your dependencies. Every time you install or remove a package vcpkg.json will be automatically updated eliminating the need to upload your dependencies to your repository. You only need to upload vcpkg.json to your repository which is much faster. It also has many more advantages, take a look at https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/manifests/

Comment: **So how do I generate the `vcpkg.json` with current dependencies?!** _I have two dependencies now 1.[cpr](https://github.com/libcpr/cpr), 2.[nlohmann-json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json)_

Comment: All info is here https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/manifests/. Please, read the docs.